# SwiftUI Animate Custom Progress Bar

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I created this custom progress view with bars for the progress, how can I animate the the green color in the next bar when it's time to go to the next element? I am looking for it to fill the bar slowly from left to right

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProgressBar(lastIndex: 8, currentIndex: 4)
            .padding(.horizontal, 23)
            .padding(.top, 10)
        Spacer()
    }
}

struct ProgressBar: View {
    var lastIndex: Int
    var currentIndex: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
            ForEach(0...lastIndex, id: \.self) { i in
                BarElement(selected: i <= currentIndex)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BarElement: View {
    var selected: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Capsule()
            .fill(selected ? .green : Color(UIColor.lightGray))
            .frame(width: 33, height: 5, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without code but if you have all separated rectangles, it should be enough using .animation(.linear) on all the rectagles, so when the values changes it should animated as you asked.

This will do what you wanted.

```
struct BarElement: View {
    var value : CGFloat = 0.0
    var selected: Bool
    

    var body: some View {
        ZStack (alignment: .leading){
            Capsule()
                .fill(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                .frame(width: 33, height: 5, alignment: .leading)
                .animation(.linear, value: selected)
        Capsule()
            .fill(.green)
            .frame(width: selected ? 33 : 0, height: 5, alignment: .leading)
            .animation(.linear, value: selected)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just posted the code, can't believe I forgot to include that, you can copy and paste it into a project to replicate

Comment: Ok so you can use the .animation(.linear, value: selected) in the Capsule code. It won't fill left to right but it will fill smoothly. If you want left to right to be achieved, you should use in the Bar Element  A Zstack where you put the gray capsule on top and the green capsule down in the code. By passing to the BarElement the value of progress, like 0 to 1, and with the .animation(..), it will fill left to right.

Comment: `struct BarElement: View {
    var value : CGFloat = 0.0
    var selected: Bool
    

    var body: some View {
        ZStack (alignment: .leading){
            Capsule()
                .fill(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                .frame(width: 33, height: 5, alignment: .leading)
                .animation(.linear, value: selected)
        Capsule()
            .fill(.green)
            .frame(width: selected ? 33 : 0, height: 5, alignment: .leading)
            .animation(.linear, value: selected)
        }
    }
}
`
This will do the magic, sorry for poor indentation

Comment: it is not animating for me

Comment: what is ```value``` for? it was never used

Comment: Sorry value was a try you are right in the end I didn't use it. Anyway was animating for me. Don't know if you have any other problem in the code maybe.

Comment: This was the content I used to try.
`struct ContentView: View {
    @State var current = 4
    var body: some View {
        ProgressBar(lastIndex: 8, currentIndex: current)
            .padding(.horizontal, 23)
            .padding(.top, 10)
        Spacer()
        Button("add"){
            current+=1
        }
    }
}`